# List Repository names on Docker Hub

Tags: docker, dockerhub

Is there any docker command to only list the names of repositories in docker hub registry?
I didn't find any on docker.io platform.

Answer (score 2):

It's not supported by default, but you can make your own script that contains multiple function in order to list repo names as well as the images within your acccount.

It can be a simple Bash Script or can embedded to your app as a tool to search repos.

1. Get your authToken by login to [dockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/v2/users/login/)
2. Using the authToken you can invoke repo listing under your account.

```
AuthToken=$(curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username": "'${username}'", "password": "'${password}'"}' https://hub.docker.com/v2/users/login/ | jq -r .token)
```

```
curl -s -H "Authorization: JWT $AuthToken" https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/${username}/?page_size=100 | jq -r '.results|.[]|.name'
```

I refer to this script from [github](https://gist.github.com/kizbitz/e59f95f7557b4bbb8bf2).

Comment: Thanks @Edcel_Cabrera_Vista

Comment: Please confirm the answer if it's solved the problem. :)